# How to Calculate the RMA, EMA, WMA values of ATR ( Average True Range) for stocks data in Pandas / Python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, data-science, finance

I have a code which works perfectly and returns the [ATR: Average True Range](https://www.fidelity.com/learning-center/trading-investing/technical-analysis/technical-indicator-guide/atr#:%7E:text=Average%20True%20Range%20(ATR)%20is,daily%2C%20weekly%2C%20or%20monthly.) but it uses [SMA: Simple Moving Average](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/sma.asp)

How could I apply the same for all of  RMA, EMA, WMA?

Here is the code:

```
def get_ATR(df, window:int=14, names:tuple = ('OPEN','CLOSE','LOW','HIGH'), return_df:bool = True):
        '''
        Get the Average True Range. Concept of Volatility
        args:
            df: Pandas Data Frame
            window: Rolling window or the period you want to consider
            names: Column names showing ('OPEN','CLOSE','LOW','HIGH') in the same order
            return_df: Whether to return the whole Df or the latest value
        '''
        Open, Close, Low, High = names
        data = df.copy()
        if data.iloc[0,0] > data.iloc[1,0]: # if the first Date entry [0,0] is > previous data entry [1,0] then it is in descending order, then reverse it for calculation
            data.sort_index(ascending=False, inplace = True)


        high_low = data[High] - data[Low]
        high_close = np.abs(data[High] - data[Close].shift())
        low_close = np.abs(data[Low] - data[Close].shift())

        ranges = pd.concat([high_low, high_close, low_close], axis=1)
        true_range = np.max(ranges, axis=1)

        ATR = true_range.rolling(window).sum()/window
        data['ATR'] = ATR
        data.sort_index(ascending=True, inplace = True)

        if return_df:
            return data

        return data.iloc[0,-1]
```

Answer (score 1):

For RMA:

```
true_range.ewm(alpha=1 / length, min_periods=length, adjust=False).mean()
```

Comment: Please format the code snippet as a code block